# NGINX not found 404 resources not loading

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, server

I am using AWS EC2 to host my webpage. I am using Nodejs server with Nginx for reverse proxy.

Node server listening to port 3000. when I go to *public_ip:3000* everything loads fine. if I go to just *public_ip* css javascript and all other resources not loading, links are not working as well.
http://13.125.246.138:3000
http://13.125.246.138

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require ('path')
const app = new express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
const cors = require('cors');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('App listening 3000')
});
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('index');
})
app.get('/about', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('about');
})
app.get('/portfolio', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('portfolio');
})
app.get('/contact', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('contact');
})
app.get('/services', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('services');
})
              
  });
```

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen[::]:80 default_server;
    root var/www/html
    server_name _;
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass 0.0.0.0:3000/;
    }
```

Comment: You have `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same `location`. Try removing `try_files`.

Comment: Your links are working fine for me though, so you fixed it?

Comment: I fixed it by removing NGINX and installing Apache